# Source identification on quote from Imam Ahmad regarding Allah's attributes

Tags: source-identification, reference-request

Can someone share the reference for where Imam Ahmad is alleged to have said the following regarding the divine attributes of Allah and whether the meaning should be affirmed or not:

> “We believe and confirm the hadiths of the Attributes without how and
> without meaning (wa la kayf wa la ma’na.)

Comment: It appears in the narration of Hanbal ibn Ishaaq who is trustworthy but disputed and discussed among hanbalis if he deviates from mainstream or if his narration is ahad as is the case here. However many of them explained what imam Ahmad might be referring to.

Comment: Since this narration is ahad, would you say that it's unlikely this can traced to Imam Ahmad?

Comment: Well Hanbal ibn Ishaaq is a student of imam Ahmad he might have asked him while they were alone. The point here is that the statement needs some explanation.